# ¿Cómo arreglo este error de pipeline en Jenkin?

Tags: jenkins, jobs, pipeline

Necesito crear un archivo con Jenkins, pero el nombre del archivo debe ser la hora + minutos actuales y me salta este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En los scripts declarativos de jenkins tienes que usar "script" para el uso de codigo "groovy".
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script

```
steps {
   script {
      def now = new Date()
      writeFile file: "${now}.txt",text: "Hola mundo"
   }
}
```